# Missing Header Options/Buttons

Tags: 3d-view, interface

[image]

It didn't happen to me but happened to someone in our group, I also found a similar question posted a year ago about the same bug, but there were no answers to that question either (or at least something that would fix it): [Header buttons missing! Please help!](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248244/header-buttons-missing-please-help)

This happened after Blender 4.0 was installed. We checked if some checkboxes are off and re-installed Blender 4.0 as well. Still nothing.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: This is my first question here, if I've made any mistakes I will gladly correct them!

Comment: Hello ! Are you using any third party addons ?

Comment: I don't think so, It's a fresh install they said (just curious, can an addon modify those? just a heads up for the future)

Comment: I think I've already seen the problem, maybe Preferences > Interface > Editors > Region Overlap or something else in the Preferences

Comment: Tried messing with the Preferences and I couldn't replicate the problem

Comment: Yes for reference addons can mess with the interface, as most of it is defined with python scripts it is easy to tweak it (and break it )

Comment: Update: It was fixed by doing a "Reset Factory Preferences" in the Preference! (for future people) Still not sure why but it worked, thank you everyone!

Comment: Addendum: Turning off Auto-Save Preference was key to make the reset work as well for some reason.