# After upgrading from Blender 3.6 to Blender 4.0 Some Options got Missing

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

The Header Options got missing is there any way or Option to get it back?

Comment: See if the last two comments here help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304902/missing-header-options-buttons

Comment: Hm, that's strange. It's definitely there in my 4.0 and I can't seem to find a way to disable it... so unfortunately I don't know how to get it back either. A bug maybe? Have you tried reinstalling or from the menu _File_ > _Defaults_ > _Factory Settings_?