# Header option gone?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, visibility, tools, mmd-tools

I've used Blender a couple of times since the new Blender 4.0 release. It did not have any problems until recently when I opened Blender the header option was gone.

The essential tools to edit are nowhere to be found. I've seen different tutorials of the new 4.0 version but apparently none of them have their header options missing.

Is there a new option to enable them or is it simply a bug?

[image]

Comment: Should be an add-on, that causes errors in interface, Check console for errors and try to disable addons one by one to find one with error.

Comment: It's been seen a couple of times before here recently. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304902/missing-header-options-buttons